# How to add an ImagePattern to a Rectangle while still maintaining the Rectangles background color

Tags: css, image, javafx

I have a chess board and I am trying to add pieces to the board. Every spot on the board is a Rectangle so I thought the best way to add pieces would be to add an ImagePattern to each Rectangle that gets a piece. The problem I encountered was when I added an ImagePattern to a Rectangle it would make the background of that Rectangle white despite what the color was before the ImagePattern was added. So my question is, is there a way for me to preserve the background color of a Rectangle after an ImagePattern is added? 
For demo purposes my code only adds one piece to the board.

```
public class ChessBoard extends Application {
  GridPane root = new GridPane();
  final int size = 8;

  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            Rectangle square = new Rectangle();
            Color color;

            if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) 
                color = Color.WHITE;
            else 
                color = Color.BLACK;

            square.setFill(color);
            root.add(square, col, row);
            if(row == 4 && col == 3){
                Image p = new Image("Peices/Black/0.png");
                ImagePattern pat = new ImagePattern(p);
                square.setFill(pat);
            }



             square.widthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(size));
            square.heightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(size));
            square.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                 square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            });
        }
    }
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for blending which is done with the BlendMode. For example:

```
 Image p = new Image("Peices/Black/0.png");
 ImagePattern pat = new ImagePattern(p);
 Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
 r1.setX(50);
 r1.setY(50);
 r1.setWidth(50);
 r1.setHeight(50);
 r1.setFill(pat);

 Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
 r.setX(50);
 r.setY(50);
 r.setWidth(50);
 r.setHeight(50);
 r.setFill(Color.BLUE);
 r.setBlendMode(BlendMode.ADD);
```

As far as I know there is no direct way to accomplish this.
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use more than a single fill with a `Rectangle`. Theoretically you could use a `Region` with multiple backgrounds, but this is probably a bad idea. Most likely you'll want at least some of the following functionality for the pieces, which will not work, if you do not make pieces their own nodes:

- Dragging a piece from one field to another
- animating moves

I recommend using a `StackPane` and put the Board in the background and put a `Pane` on top of it to place the pieces. Simply use `ImageView`s for the pieces.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane board = new GridPane();
    Region[][] fields = new Region[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        Region[] flds = fields[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < flds.length; j++) {
            Region field = new Region();
            flds[j] = field;
            field.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        }
        board.addRow(i, flds);
    }

    // use 1/8 of the size of the Grid for each field
    RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
    rowConstraints.setPercentHeight(100d / 8);
    ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100d / 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        board.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        board.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
    }

    Pane piecePane = new Pane();
    StackPane root = new StackPane(board, piecePane);

    NumberBinding boardSize = Bindings.min(root.widthProperty(), root.heightProperty());

    ImageView queen = new ImageView("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Chess_qdt45.svg/480px-Chess_qdt45.svg.png");
    DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.WHITE, 2, 1, 0, 0);

    // drop shadow for black piece on black field
    queen.setEffect(shadow);

    // trigger move to topleft field on mouse click
    queen.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        Node source = (Node) evt.getSource();
        TranslateTransition animation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), source);
        Region targetRegion = fields[0][0];
        final PositionChangeListener listener = (PositionChangeListener) source.getUserData();
        listener.setField(null);
        animation.setByX(targetRegion.getLayoutX() - source.getLayoutX());
        animation.setByY(targetRegion.getLayoutY() - source.getLayoutY());
        animation.setOnFinished(e -> {
            source.setTranslateX(0);
            source.setTranslateY(0);
            listener.setField(targetRegion);
        });
        animation.play();
    });

    PositionChangeListener changeListener = new PositionChangeListener(queen);
    queen.setUserData(changeListener);
    changeListener.setField(fields[4][3]);

    // board size should be as large as possible but at most the min of the parent sizes
    board.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    board.maxWidthProperty().bind(boardSize);
    board.maxHeightProperty().bind(boardSize);

    // same size for piecePane
    piecePane.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    piecePane.maxWidthProperty().bind(boardSize);
    piecePane.maxHeightProperty().bind(boardSize);

    // add piece to piecePane
    piecePane.getChildren().add(queen);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private static class PositionChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Bounds> {

    private final ImageView piece;

    public PositionChangeListener(ImageView piece) {
        this.piece = piece;
    }

    private Region currentField;

    public void setField(Region newRegion) {
        // register/unregister listeners to bounds changes of associated field
        if (currentField != null) {
            currentField.boundsInParentProperty().removeListener(this);
        }
        currentField = newRegion;
        if (newRegion != null) {
            newRegion.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(this);
            changed(null, null, newRegion.getBoundsInParent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
        // align piece with field
        piece.setLayoutX(newValue.getMinX());
        piece.setLayoutY(newValue.getMinY());
        piece.setFitHeight(newValue.getHeight());
        piece.setFitWidth(newValue.getWidth());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been researching awhile for this and I didn't think I would be able to do it but I Just wanted to make sure. I really like your suggestion of using a StackPane, I am going to try it.

Comment: fabian, I Haven been messing around with this code for awhile now and I just had a quick question, If I wanted to add a MouseListener to each individual square and to see if that square is a legal move for a certain piece, where would be the best place to do add the Listener? I have been trying to figure it for the the last couple days and nothing I have tried seem to work. Thank you so much for this example by the way, I have already learned a ton from it!